# Binary Search output issue?

Tags: java, search, binary

This is a first for using a binary search for me, so I've run into a small issue (hopefully!) first the program, it allows the user to type in a random number, and if that number matches any book it outputs the title.

```
class b {

    String book1, book2;

    b () {
        book1 = "Wicked Awesome Title";
        book2 = "How to Read a Book";

        public static Book getBook(Book [] A, int left, int right, String bookTitle) {
            int middle;
            Book found = null;

            /**Your average Joe binary search...*/
            while (found == null && left <= right) {
                //If middle item == 0, returns true
                middle = (left + right)/2;
                int compare = A[middle].sameTitle(bookTitle);
                if (compare == 0) {
                    found = A[middle];
                } else {
                    if (compare >0) {
                        right = middle -1;
                    } else {
                        left = middle + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return found;
        }
```

Now this is the problem, after pressing the "find" book button,

```
private void findActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    String book1 = "Wicked Awesome Title";
    String book2 = "How to Read a Book";;

    Book b = getBook(book1, book2); //this entire line is underlined, 
    if (b != null){
        itsATextField.setText("You've found the book " + b);
    }
```

so what am I missing to make this work? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your `getBook` function is declared as:

```
public static Book getBook(Book [] A, int left, int right, String bookTitle) {
```

When you try to call it only with two String arguments:

```
Book b = getBook(book1, book2);
```

If you want to call a function, you must call it with the expected arguments.

Also, not sure if related or not but you'r missing `}` at the end of the constructor.

BTW, adding the error you get will help us help you.